# error al subir imágenes con Php

Tags: php, fileupload, upload

tengo 2 archivos: index.php y upload.php

en el index.php

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="descripcion"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="precio" placeholder="precio"><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="upload">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

en upload.php tengo

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

// Ruta de carga de imagen        
$target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

//conexion base de datos
$db = getDB();

//lo que recibe del formulario
$image          =   $_FILES['image']['name'];
$title          =   $_POST['titulo'];
$description    =   $_POST['descripcion'];
$price          =   $_POST['precio'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO imagen (id, titulo, descripcion, precio, ruta_image) VALUES (NULL,'$title','$description','$price','$image')";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['name']['tmp_name'], $target);
if ($result) {
    $msg = "imagen subida correctamente";
    echo $msg;
}else{
    $msg = "Ocurrio un error";
    echo $msg;
}
}
```

la inserción de los datos a la base de datos si se realiza correctamente, lo que pasa es que la imagen no se sube, y muestra el mensaje de error que esta en el else.

espero su apoyo con esto, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pon en `$target`  una ruta estática conocida y que sepas que tienes permisos de escritura, tal como haces (`basename($_FILES['image']['name'])`)  creo que vas a obtener la ruta temporal de subida.  Una vez que te funcione puedes parametrizar esa ruta definitiva e ir creando carpetas según necesites.

Comment: Verifica si en la ruta de la carpeta "images" donde guardas las imágenes, tengas permiso de escritura.